# Some Opencart's modules doesn't support UTF8 and showing ???? instead of characters

Tags: mysqli, utf-8, opencart

in some cases, modules for Opencart doesn't support RTL languages and UTF8 characters and it will show `?????????` characters instead of your Persian/Arabic characters.
what I should do with these modules to show up my characters correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is several ways:

1) **Use sql query:**

In this case you can use some queries like bellow:

```
$this->db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$this->db->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8;");
$this->db->query("SET character_set_connection=utf8;");
```

You should put these queries in your database driver file. here I am using mysqli then I should put codes in `mysqli.php` in this directory `opencart\system\library\db\mysqli.php` like bellow:

```
public function __construct($hostname, $username, $password, $database, $port = '3306') {
        $this->link = new \mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database, $port);

    if ($this->link->connect_error) {
        trigger_error('Error: Could not make a database link (' . $this->link->connect_errno . ') ' . $this->link->connect_error);
        exit();
    }

    $this->link->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $this->link->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
    $this->link->query("SET character_set_connection=utf8;");
    $this->link->query("SET SQL_MODE = ''");
}
```

2) **Change database charset:**

But is some cases it wont solve your problem. then you should check your database `Collation` for all tables and columns inside tables and you should set it to `utf8_general_ci`.

To do this you can use `ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE_NAME DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;` to change character set for Tables and use `ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE_NAME CHANGE COLUMN_NAME CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;` to change columns character set.

Please note, if there is so many tables and columns, you can export your file to `.sql` format and then open it with notepad and replace all `latin1` (it's my file charset, maybe it be different in your file), to `utf8` and save it and use this new database file.

3) **Change file format:**

In this case, you should open your file with notepad and use `file menu / save as`, and in save as windows change `encoding` to `UTF-8` (it mostly help if the file is using `echo or print` to show some strings...

Hope it helps.